# Row values should be one by one in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm stuck in a particular point of MySQL. I have three table, each has foreign key relationship. Three fields of **TitleOrder** table are **gt1,gt2 and gt3** which are indicating **p1,p2 and p3** of **Percentage** table respectively. I need each data of **TitleOrder and Percentage** should be one by one in correct format.

I draw an image which shows what should be the expected table.

**Note : Data of three tables is dynamic**

[image]

Comment: show your code: what have you tried so far? what is the query you run and what is the result you get? So far it is a "write a query for me" request that none here will answer

Comment: @LelioFaieta I couldn't understand how to start, just give me a small clue, I will code and post it here, now Im trying with `case when... then... end`, is that a starting point?

Comment: try to look at pivot tables with mysql

Comment: Typically, enumerated column names are symptomatic of poor design. You may want to rethink your schema.

Comment: @Strawberry I could understand, I changed the schema. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to `UNPIVOT` the data. But unfortunately MySQL does not have any function for it, so you will need to replicate it by using a `union all` or `union` (depending on your dataset) query.

The below query should work for you.

```
SELECT 
    s.surveyId, s.surveyName, t.gt, t.p
FROM
    survey s
    JOIN
    (SELECT 
        gt1 AS gt, p1 AS p, t.surveyId
    FROM
        TitleOrder t JOIN Percentage p on t.titleOrderId = p.titleOrderId

    UNION ALL 

    SELECT 
        gt2 AS gt, p2 AS p, t.surveyId
    FROM
        TitleOrder t JOIN Percentage p on t.titleOrderId = p.titleOrderId 

    UNION ALL 

    SELECT 
        gt3 AS gt, p3 AS p, t.surveyId
    FROM
        TitleOrder t JOIN Percentage p on t.titleOrderId = p.titleOrderId
) t ON t.surveyId = s.surveyId
ORDER BY s.surveyId , t.surveyId;
```

But you might want to re-look at your schema as more the number of columns, more the unions.